# Detect the discord system welcome message

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I want to detect the discord system welcome message, and give reaction to it, but I couldn't find out what message type that is. (I am using discord.js v13)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [message type](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Message?scrollTo=type) of the system welcome message is [`GUILD_MEMBER_JOIN`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/MessageType). You can find out by logging the system message.